# Unable to login to CentOS 7 after reinstalling Java

Tags: centos, boot, login, java

I am using CentOS 7 and I had Java 1.7 installed with `openjdk` in my system but I wanted Java 8 so I removed Java 1.7 by the command:

```
yum remove java-1.*
```

Then I installed java normally by `tar.gz` package everything works normally until I restarted the system. The problem is that whenever I enter the password in my login screen the screen comes back again to the same login screen its like a loop I type the password enter it then a blank screen shows for seconds and then login screen appears again.

I can't seem to figure out what to do where to start looking the problem.

Comment: Can you log in as root?  Can you log in at a console? Press Ctl-Alt-F2  (or F3 etc) until you see a text login prompt.  Try logging in there.  Try logging in as root user.  If you get in, run (as root) `setenforce 0` and then return to the GUI (Ctl-Alt-F1) and try logging in again.  Also, check permissions on your home directory.  It's unlikely that the change of Java caused this as CentOS's desktop doesn't depend on Java - it's more likely that you've accidentally changed something else or a completely unconnected issue has arisen at the same time. But I could be wrong :-)

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like something in your graphical environment (maybe your window manager) would like to have that Java version, or it is looking for it in a way you didn't cater for (like, have you looked at `/etc/alternatives`?), so your graphical session immediately ends, throwing you back to the graphical login screen.

You can use Ctrl-Alt-F2 on the login screen to swith to a text console to log in, and I guess the first thing to do would be to reinstall CentOS' Java. (BTW, in my experience, there is no problem with having multiple versions of Java installed. I tend to put my manually installed ones in `/opt`, but then, I don't usually care if system tools use the old version.)